# how can I constrain a foreign key relationship where it may refer to multiple other tables?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database, rdbms

I have a table called inventory_movements , and I'm planing to save the products movements in and out the warehouse , it has fields like

```
1- movement_id(PK)
2- product_id(FK)
3- quantity int
4- unit_price decimal
5- movement ENUM('in','out')
6- date datetime
7- ????????? (reference )(e.g.  sell(out)- purchase(in)- fire loss(out)
 - sales return (in) - purchase return (out)
```

my problem is that I want to store the reference of the movement (the cause of the movement) whither it is the order id , or purchase id , purchase return id, .... etc

but I also want to make a constrain on this field to make sure that no invalid data (e.g. not exist purchase) will be stored in the database, of curse I can't make one foreign key references many tables (sales, purchases, purchase returns , ...etc)

a very bad solution is to add column for every reference type (sell id, purchase id, sales return id,etc.. ) and fill the right one in each movement and let the others null , but this is of curse against normalization and I can't add any more reference later.

**what can I do in this situation ?**

*please consider that I'm very newbie, thanks*

Comment: you either have referential integrity on a column #7 or you don't. In your current rough draft, you won't

Comment: @Drew No, I don't have referential integrity , the sales invoices have different serialization than the purchases , than the returns, ... etc (meaning that I may have a purchase invoice and sales invoice with **the same** ID number , So in this case , do I have any way to make a foreign key constraint on column 7 so I don't end up with a reference that is not exist in the system (either a sales invoice or a purchase invoice) ?

Comment: you can use NULL, and it is generally frowned upon as a violation of sensibility but a work-around. If you want me to provide a complete answer I will, but it boils down to this for how I would do it: each transaction type would have its own dedicated table. It would support full referential integrity. And the use of `union` could achieve a chronological view of things

Comment: @Drew thank you very much , I don't want to waste your time with a complete answer , but I don't think I get it right, do you mean by `you can use NULL` is that I make a dedicated column for each type of  transaction references, and use only one column and set all the others NULL ?

Comment: I would rather show you the dedicated tables approach with referential integrity (assuming you don't have that already in the below single answer). Otherwise I am doing an answer with NULLs that I wouldn't even want to defend. But some people do it. So even to comment on NULLs seems irresponsible of me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few approaches.  One is to have one foreign key per table type with a constraint that ensures that exactly one is not null.  I agree that is clunky but some people prefer it (David Fetter, for example, has blogged about the benefits of this approach).

Another approach is to factor out the common parts of the referenced tables into a single, easily referenced table.  If you cannot do this, you can have a trigger-maintained table instead.  That would mean something like:

1. A transaction documents table
2. A table for sales/purchase data (or maybe different tables for this).

If that cannot be done then you have another table which just stores the ids, relevant tables, and an id for reference purpose, and that is maintained with a trigger, then you have a referring constraint there.

Either way, long-run you are probably going to end up with the second solution (a master transaction journal, and then other tables that extend it).

(Original design question answer below.

Depending on how you want to address this I can see one of two ways of doing it.

The first is to use a basic convention of positive numbers coming in and negative numbers going out.  This works for global movements (purchases and sales) but it breaks down for local movements (moving between warehouses).

One option here is to have a separate "states" table which represents both global and local states.  For example, purchases, sales, different warehouses, etc.  Then you represent the transfer as a graph link between the state.  You can also have a documents table which can represent purchases and sales, with appropriate classifictions etc.  This allows  three-way relationship between an in-state, an out-state, and a document. For example a sale could have an in-state as inventory (or a particular warehouse), an out-state of sale, and a document of the sales invoice.

Of course you can do both, storing global inventory in one way and warehouse movements in the other.

Comment: thank you very much for your time that will help me when I make a bigger database that has many internal warehouses.   but my problem is not about handling the in-between movements, **I only want to make a foreign key constraint on the reference column** so I wont end up with a reference that is not exist neither in the sales invoices or purchases invoice, ..etc

Comment: Thanks. Will amend appropriately

Comment: answer amended.  I also edited the question to make it clearer.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for complete help.  I will go for the second approach. create new table for all company documents that has 3 columns`( id, document_type, document_id)` as it looks more organized than the mess of having one column per document type (sales invoices, purchases,.. etc).. and then make the inventory table references this documents table.. but I will still have the same problem as I have no FK constraint on the `documents table.document_id column`, I just moved the same problem from the inventory table to the documents table, but I think there is no other way than triggers as you said